# Format whole number and decimals with two decimal places

Tags: c#, string.format

Can someone help jog my memory or point me in the right direction. I'm not sure what strategy to go with here, but I have an input control that will accept integers and decimal. I want to save the value always having two decimal places so if the user enters 35 then 35.00, if 35.00 then 35.00, if 35.5 then 35.50, and so on.

I'm using string format right now

```
 string.Format("{0:0.00}", val);
```

Returns (not what I'm looking for) :

35 : 35
35.2 : 35.2

Comment: I bet `val` is of type `string`.

Comment: I guess there is no document on internet or you searched a lot and couldn't find one.

Comment: You have to use it: `string something = string.Format("{0:0.00}", val);`

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech, I'm well aware.

Comment: That's right @LucasTrzesniewski, long day causes my brain to mush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is val?

Your format string should work if val is numeric.

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.00}", 35));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.00}", "35"));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.00}", int.Parse("35")));
        }
    }
```

Prints

```
35.00 
35
35.00
```

If val is string then it will not work. You need to parse to numeric type first. Use TryParse to validate the input for actual numeric.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was just missing a mundane detail. Yes, my question was rushed, my brain was in a panic and `val` was type `string`.